# Can't NIntegrate my NDSolve results

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to `NIntegrate` my `NDSolve` result. I don't have a exact function form because it is coming from the `NDSolve` result. It looks like `Integrate` only permit numerical forms.

The function `y1[t]` could be solved through several differential equations:

```
S1 = NDSolve[{y1'[t] == -0.9*y1[t] + SuperPlus[z1][t] + 
     SuperMinus[z2][t] + 0.005*SuperPlus[z1][t]*y2[t] + 
     0.008*SuperMinus[z2][t]*y2[t] + 0.005*x[t]*SuperPlus[z1][t] + 
     0.008*x[t]*SuperMinus[z2][t] - 0.008*y1[t]*SuperMinus[z1][t] - 
     0.005*y1[t]*SuperPlus[z2][t], 
   y2'[t] == -0.8*y2[t] + SuperPlus[z2][t] + SuperMinus[z1][t] + 
     0.008*y1[t]*SuperMinus[z1][t] + 0.005*y1[t]*SuperPlus[z2][t] + 
     0.005*x[t]*SuperPlus[z2][t] + 0.008*x[t]*SuperMinus[z1][t] - 
     0.005*SuperPlus[z1][t]*y2[t] - 0.008*SuperMinus[z2][t]*y2[t],
   SuperPlus[z1]'[t] == 0.63*y1[t] - SuperPlus[z1][t],
   SuperPlus[z2]'[t] == 0.64*y2[t] - SuperPlus[z2][t],
   SuperMinus[z1]'[t] == 0.27*y1[t] - SuperMinus[z1][t],
   SuperMinus[z2]'[t] == 0.16*y2[t] - SuperMinus[z2][t],
   x[t] + y1[t] + y2[t] + SuperPlus[z1][t] + SuperPlus[z2][t] + 
     SuperMinus[z1][t] + SuperMinus[z2][t] == 50000000,
   SuperPlus[z1][0] == SuperPlus[z2][0] == SuperMinus[z1][0] == 
    SuperMinus[z2][0] == 0, y1[0] == y2[0] == 10000000, 
   x[0] == 30000000}, {x, y1, y2, SuperPlus[z1], SuperMinus[z1], 
   SuperPlus[z2], SuperMinus[z2]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

The result is quite clear in image:

```
Plot[Evaluate[y1[t] /. S1], {t, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The image is here: [image: y1[t]]

While, I can't use `NIntegrate` or `Integrate` to this function `y1[t]`. It doesn't give me result.

```
NIntegrate[Boole[y1[t]], {t, 0, 100}]
```

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Boole[y1[t]] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,100}}. >>

What should I do? Shall I use Monte Carlo method??

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What, precisely, do you wish to do but are unable?

Comment: problem is updated and clarified.

Comment: Hint: If `Plot[Evaluate[y1[t] /. S1], {t, 0, 100}]` works, then `NIntegrate[Evaluate[y1[t] /. S1], {t, 0, 100}]` probably will.  The similarity in the syntax of related functions is by design.

Comment: Why did you not include the error message?  Is it not a hint to what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
NIntegrate[y1[t] /. S1, {t, 0, 100}]
```

yields

```
(* {1.17532*10^9} *}
```

which seems reasonable.  Using `Boole` was the problem.

Comment: I can't believe it is so simple ~!!!! Thanks you very much. You really save my day!

Answer (score 2):

As shown by [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey)
, `NIntegrate` can solve your problem, but I just want to add, `Integrate` can actually handle `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
int[t_] = Integrate[y1[t] /. S1, t]
```

The output is an `InterpolatingFunction` representing the definite integral of $y_1(t)$ over $[0,t]$. The advantage of this approach is, you don't need to integrate again and again if you want to know the integral at other points. Just compare the following:

```
Table[int@t, {t, 0, 100, 1/10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.015558, Null} *)
int2[tt_] := NIntegrate[y1[t] /. S1, {t, 0, tt}]
Table[int2@t, {t, 0, 100, 1/10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.340323, Null} *)
```

Then

同学，如果你现在所获得的两个答案中的某一个真的帮到了你的话，你完全可以点一下你所满意的答案旁边的小勾（也就是上面那条评论里所说的[Click the checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/284701)）来把它采纳（accept）了的。

Comment: something went wong...

Comment: @chris Yeah, after trying for times I noticed the original timing is inaccurate. Modified, thx for pointing out.